# Delete folder in registry entry

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, windows-registry, shortcuts

I have a question regarding the problem of deleting a **folder** of a registry path with a **.bat** or **cmd** shortcut, preferably a .bat.

Here is my problem:

I want to delete (for example) the folder "classes" in the path `Computer/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/CLASSES`. I do not want to delete anything specific in there just the whole folder itself, but how do i do it with a shortcut such as a .bat?

I don't want to mess up anything therefore I'm asking here for some advice or rather a solution.

Comment: It's called a _registry key_, not "folder". That should make searching for it easier.

Comment: `reg.exe delete keyName` can accomplish what you want in a .bat or .cmd.  However, I would probably avoid deleting that "CLASSES" registry key from your example above, since you state that "I don't want to mess up anything".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using reg.exe, which is supplied as part of Windows. To learn how to use it, read its built-in help with `reg /?`

Deleting stuff from the registry is done with `reg delete`, and you can get help on that with `reg delete /?`

You can delete a whole registry "folder" with `reg delete pathname`, but I'd strongly advise you to be careful about that, since you can mess up your machine *really easily* this way. Look at `reg save /?` and `reg restore /?` to learn how to back up parts of your registry by saving them to files, and how to restore them from the backups.